# Kerio VPN client removing problem

Tags: uninstall, vpn, client

I have installed Kerio VPN client from its `.deb` file but it didn't finish its installation process and software center was frozen until I force quit it.

And now I cannot update or install anything because first it goes to Kerio VPN client and freezes.

I have tried installing synaptic package manager to find a way to remove it, but I can't install it because the software center freezes before I can install anything.

How can I fix this?

I'm using Ubuntu 64 bit 14.04 .

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem for anyone that has the same problem the solution is :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After typing above command you should configure Kerio VPN server and username and password, then your connection goes through Kerio VPN and you can use it.

If you want to get rid of kerio vpn for good :

- open software center and install synaptic package manager
- open synaptic package manager and type `kerio`

It will show you Kerio VPN control packages; right click on it and click **completely remove** then **apply**